# Open link below menu bar html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a menu page for links which are in a href form. I know it has a target blank which opens it in another tab but is there any way that whenever the user choose a link, the link will open in the same page and the menu form will be transformed into a simple menu bar at the top? I am new to this field and still trying to learn. Is this possible? please help

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons\">  
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js'></script> 
<title>DOE Dynamic Dashboard</title>
 <link rel = "icon" href = "http://www.iconhot.com/icon/png/free-arrow/256/pie-chart-4.png" type = "image/x-icon"> 
</head>

<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel&display=swap');
{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.strips {
  min-height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: white;
}
 .strips__strip {
  will-change: width, left, z-index, height;
  position: absolute;
  width: 20%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
}
 .strips__strip:nth-child(1) {
  left: 0;
}
 .strips__strip:nth-child(2) {
  left: 20vw;
}
 .strips__strip:nth-child(3) {
  left: 40vw;
}
 .strips__strip:nth-child(4) {
  left: 60vw;
}
 .strips__strip:nth-child(5) {
  left: 80vw;
}
 .strips__strip:nth-child(1) .strip__content {
  background:#29363B;
  transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  animation-name: strip1;
  animation-delay: 0.1s;
}
 .strips__strip:nth-child(2) .strip__content {
  background: #EA495F;
  transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  animation-name: strip2;
  animation-delay: 0.2s;
}
 .strips__strip:nth-child(3) .strip__content {
  background: #F4837D;
  transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
  animation-name: strip3;
  animation-delay: 0.3s;
}
 .strips__strip:nth-child(4) .strip__content {
  background: #FAA664;
  transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  animation-name: strip4;
  animation-delay: 0.4s;
}
 .strips__strip:nth-child(5) .strip__content {
  background: #99B998;
  transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  animation-name: strip5;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
 @media screen and (max-width: 760px) {
  .strips__strip {
   min-height: 20vh;
 }
  .strips__strip:nth-child(1) {
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
 }
  .strips__strip:nth-child(2) {
   top: 20vh;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
 }
  .strips__strip:nth-child(3) {
   top: 40vh;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
 }
  .strips__strip:nth-child(4) {
   top: 60vh;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
 }
  .strips__strip:nth-child(5) {
   top: 80vh;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
 }
}
 .strips .strip__content {
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
}
 .strips .strip__content:hover:before {
  transform: skew(-30deg) scale(3) translate(0, 0);
  opacity: 0.1;
}
 .strips .strip__content:before {
  <!-- content: ""; -->
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
  opacity: 0.05;
  transform-origin: center center;
  transform: skew(-30deg) scaleY(1) translate(0, 0);
  transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
}
 .strips .strip__inner-text {
  will-change: transform, opacity;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 70%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.5);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
}
 .strips__strip--expanded {
  width: 100%;
  top: 0 !important;
  left: 0 !important;
  z-index: 3;
  cursor: default;
}
 @media screen and (max-width: 760px) {
  .strips__strip--expanded {
   min-height: 100vh;
 }
}
 .strips__strip--expanded .strip__content:hover:before {
  transform: skew(-30deg) scale(1) translate(0, 0);
  opacity: 0.05;
}
 .strips__strip--expanded .strip__title {
  opacity: 0;
}
 .strips__strip--expanded .strip__inner-text {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
}
 .strip__title {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 2vw;
  color: white;
  transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
}
 @media screen and (max-width: 760px) {
  .strip__title {
   font-size: 28px;
 }
}
 .strip__close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 3vw;
  top: 3vw;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
  cursor: pointer;
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
}
 .strip__close--show {
  opacity: 1;
}
 @keyframes strip1 {
  0% {
   transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
 }
  100% {
   transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 }
}
 @keyframes strip2 {
  0% {
   transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
 }
  100% {
   transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 }
}
 @keyframes strip3 {
  0% {
   transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
 }
  100% {
   transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 }
}
 @keyframes strip4 {
  0% {
   transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
 }
  100% {
   transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 }
}
 @keyframes strip5 {
  0% {
   transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
 }
  100% {
   transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 }
}

 body {
  font-family: 'Abel', sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-rendering: geometricPrecision;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
 h1, h2 {
  font-weight: 300;
}
 .fa {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
}
 h2 {
  font-size: 36px;
  margin: 0 0 16px;
}
 p {
  margin: 0 0 16px;
}
a {
  background:
     linear-gradient(
       to right,
       var(--mainColor) 0%,
       var(--mainColor) 5px,
       transparent 5px
     );
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-size: 100%;
  color: #000;
  padding-left: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  background:
     linear-gradient(
       to right,
       var(--mainColor) 0%,
       var(--mainColor) 5px,
       transparent
     );
}

:root {
  --mainColor: white;
}

</style>


<script>
var Expand = (function() {
  var tile = $('.strips__strip');
  var tileLink = $('.strips__strip > .strip__content');
  var tileText = tileLink.find('.strip__inner-text');
  var stripClose = $('.strip__close');
  
  var expanded  = false;

  var open = function() {
      
    var tile = $(this).parent();

      if (!expanded) {
        tile.addClass('strips__strip--expanded');
        // add delay to inner text
        tileText.css('transition', 'all .5s .3s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1)');
        stripClose.addClass('strip__close--show');
        stripClose.css('transition', 'all .6s 1s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1)');
        expanded = true;
      } 
    };
  
  var close = function() {
    if (expanded) {
      tile.removeClass('strips__strip--expanded');
      // remove delay from inner text
      tileText.css('transition', 'all 0.15s 0 cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1)');
      stripClose.removeClass('strip__close--show');
      stripClose.css('transition', 'all 0.2s 0s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1)')
      expanded = false;
    }
  }

    var bindActions = function() {
      tileLink.on('click', open);
      stripClose.on('click', close);
    };

    var init = function() {
      bindActions();
    };

    return {
      init: init
    };

  }());

Expand.init();
</script>


<body>
 <section class="strips">
  <article class="strips__strip">
    <div class="strip__content">
          <a href="#" target="_blank" class="strip__title">ONE</a>
    </div>
  </article>
  
  <article class="strips__strip">
    <div class="strip__content">
      <a href="#" target="_blank" class="strip__title">TWO</a>
    </div>
  </article>
  
  <article class="strips__strip">
    <div class="strip__content">
     <a href="#" target="_blank" class="strip__title">THREE</a>
 </div>
  </article>
  
  <article class="strips__strip">
    <div class="strip__content">
     <a href="#" target="_blank" class="strip__title">FOUR</a>
    </div>
  </article>
  
  <article class="strips__strip">
    <div class="strip__content">
      <a href="#" target="_blank" class="strip__title">FIVE</a>
    </div>
  </article>
  <i class="fa fa-close strip__close"></i>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes, it's possiable, my approach would be to
1. create another menu which is hidden till someone clicks link
2. change css classes upon click

Comment: Remove the `target="_blank" and in any page that it's not this (the homepage?) present a bar menu and don't use this menu,

Comment: erm... don't use the _blank??

Answer (score 1):

This might not be what the OP initially wanted but below you can find my two cents on this by using containers. Instead of having an anchor to redirect the user altogether, I would hide the info away from him unless he clicked on the 'link' (while hiding the others).

OP tagged this as JavaScript but I saw Jquery was used thus the answer contains Jquery.

I apologize in advance for poor attention to details. I'm at work and I did create this in a rush.

```js
//Attach a click event for each of the elements that would act as a link
$("li").each(function(index,el){
el.onclick = function() {
//Upon clicking one of the elements, check ALL the elements once again.
//If the elements are not the one that have been clicked, hide it, otherwise expand it.
 $("li").each((indexSec,elSec)=>{
   if (el !== elSec) {
        elSec.style.height = "0"
   } else {
     el.style.height = "200px"
   }
 });
}
})
```

```css
body {
  background: white;

}

ul {
  display: block;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100vw;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  position: absolute;
  height:75px;
  list-style-type: none
}

ul li {
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  transition:.1s;
  overflow:hidden;
}

ul li p {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin:0;
  position:relative;
  height:50px;
    text-align:center;
  width:100%;
  line-height: 50px;
}

ul li:hover {
  background: grey;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="myUl">
  <li>
    <p class="li-title">One</p>
    <p class="li-content">One - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla id congue risus. Morbi imperdiet posuere justo, eget lacinia nulla iaculis ut. In vitae odio bibendum, ornare mauris sit amet, egestas purus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec fermentum porta massa, ultrices consectetur nibh molestie vitae. Nulla facilisi. Nulla ullamcorper lectus at vehicula tincidunt.</p>
    </li>
  <li>
    <p class="li-title">Two</p>
    <p class="li-content">Two - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla id congue risus. Morbi imperdiet posuere justo, eget lacinia nulla iaculis ut. In vitae odio bibendum, ornare mauris sit amet, egestas purus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec fermentum porta massa, ultrices consectetur nibh molestie vitae. Nulla facilisi. Nulla ullamcorper lectus at vehicula tincidunt</p>
    </li>
      <li>
    <p class="li-title">Three</p>
    <p class="li-content">Three - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla id congue risus. Morbi imperdiet posuere justo, eget lacinia nulla iaculis ut. In vitae odio bibendum, ornare mauris sit amet, egestas purus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec fermentum porta massa, ultrices consectetur nibh molestie vitae. Nulla facilisi. Nulla ullamcorper lectus at vehicula tincidunt</p>
    </li>
      <li>
    <p class="li-title">Four</p>
    <p class="li-content">Four - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla id congue risus. Morbi imperdiet posuere justo, eget lacinia nulla iaculis ut. In vitae odio bibendum, ornare mauris sit amet, egestas purus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec fermentum porta massa, ultrices consectetur nibh molestie vitae. Nulla facilisi. Nulla ullamcorper lectus at vehicula tincidunt</p>
    </li>
      <li>
    <p class="li-title">Five</p>
    <p class="li-content">Five - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla id congue risus. Morbi imperdiet posuere justo, eget lacinia nulla iaculis ut. In vitae odio bibendum, ornare mauris sit amet, egestas purus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec fermentum porta massa, ultrices consectetur nibh molestie vitae. Nulla facilisi. Nulla ullamcorper lectus at vehicula tincidunt</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this and open links from the menu bar on the same page as opposed to a new page, you will need to remove `target="_blank"` from your navigation links.

### Updated Code:

```
<section class="strips">
 <article class="strips__strip">
  <div class="strip__content">
   <a href="#" class="strip__title">ONE</a>
  </div>
 </article>

 <article class="strips__strip">
  <div class="strip__content">
   <a href="#" class="strip__title">TWO</a>
  </div>
 </article>

 <article class="strips__strip">
  <div class="strip__content">
   <a href="#" class="strip__title">THREE</a>
  </div>
 </article>

 <article class="strips__strip">
  <div class="strip__content">
   <a href="#" class="strip__title">FOUR</a>
  </div>
 </article>

 <article class="strips__strip">
  <div class="strip__content">
   <a href="#" class="strip__title">FIVE</a>
  </div>
 </article>
 <i class="fa fa-close strip__close"></i>
</section>
```

As you'll be opening the nav links on the same page, you'll want to add the navigation bar code to the webpage you're clicking to. This will ensure the navigation bar is transformed back to it's original state.

Eg - if you're clicking to a webpage named `test.html`, you will initially need to update the `href` within your anchor links to be `href="test.html"`. Thereafter you will create a new file named `test.html` and add the navigation bar code to that page also.